# Form to insert data in database works, but does not show success-page

Tags: php, forms

I've a simple order-form on my website. If I click the submit-button the the form will send the data to my database. This works. But it does not show the success.php - it only shows the start.php again. So there must be a mistake. On my previous hoster it worked. But now I have a new one.

Here's my php-script (start.php):

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pw") or die ("No connection to db possible"); 
mysql_select_db("db", $con) or die ("No connection to db possible");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $postvar)
    $_POST[$key] = stripslashes($postvar);

$_POST['name'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$_POST['strasse'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['strasse']);
$_POST['plz'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['plz']);
$_POST['ort'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ort']);
$_POST['mail'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
$_POST['anzahl'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['anzahl']);



$sql = "INSERT INTO `bestellungen` (`name`,`strasse`,`plz`,`ort`,`mail`,`anzahl`,`datetime`)
                VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['strasse']."', '".$_POST['plz']."', '".$_POST['ort']."', '".$_POST['mail']."', '".$_POST['anzahl']."', '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."');";

$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
mysql_close($con);

?> 

<?php Header("Location: success.php");
exit();
?>

<?php

} else { ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work because `header('Location: success.php')` needs to happen before you output anything to the browser. You seem to have gaps before that is called.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result) echo mysql_error();
mysql_close($con);

// Now its time for the header!
header("Location: success.php");
exit();
```

Comment: You're right. I didn't know that the PHP-code has to be at the top of my file and AFTER it I have to write my HTML-code. Thanks! Anyway, I am wondering, why this worked at my previous hoster.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have any output before the header() redirection.

Check your script for possible errors, warnings or notices, any of these will output text and the redirection will no happen.

Answer (score 1):

So far, whenever I found this kind of problem; there must be two reasons I often do. Either I print any html code before the header function or I don't realize that my success.php also redirect to start.php.

Maybe you can check either of these two exist in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I put the PHP-code in the middle of my file and there were HTML-code before it. I put the PHP-code to the top of my start.php and now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Format it this way.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql,$con);
if (!$result) { 

    echo mysql_error();

} else {

   Header("Location: success.php");
}

mysql_close($con);

?>
```